# How can I show custom titles on my table fields with OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, server

I have a server with Geoserver, Apache and OpenLayers and it displays the map okay; I can see my data with an `OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud` call and it shows the content of my layer.

I want to know if it's possible to show custom titles for my data instead of the ones in the  table.

Example:

I have **COSTRUC** field and I want to show **Construction**

So there is any chance to do it with Openlayers?

Answer (score 2):

You can control it pretty much every aspect of the html returned using the FreeMarker templates in GeoServer - see http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/freemarker.html for details.